# XML Issue: Loading layout for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am probably just misusing the XML, but I'm trying to create a layout for a list view row, but I seem to be failing miserably.

I have this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/detailsTextView"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/detailsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In hopes that I will be able to add a layout that is 100dp in height to my `ListView` and have two `TextView`s inside of it. However, when I try to set it up like so:

```
public View getView(int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowContents = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_view_cell, null);
    TextView titleView = (TextView)rowContents.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    titleView.setText(titles[position]);
    TextView detailsView = (TextView)rowContents.findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView);
    detailsView.setText(details[position]);

    return rowContents;
}
```

It's giving me a row with only my detailsView `TextView`with a `wrap_content` height, it seems. The titleView is nowhere to be seen and I would assume the rowContents isn't being set either, otherwise the height would be 100dp, right?

I know I should be reusing the old view and setting its contents, but I just made this up quickly as a test.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the lower TextView with `layout_below` instead:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

(Otherwise you could "lock" `titleTextView` into the upper lefthand corner, which might force `detailsTextView` to move down.)

But you should watch this [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) by one of Android's lead programmers, it gives great detail on how to make an efficient adapter.

Comment: I think it is top left, but @Sam is right, when there is no layout parameter the view is stuck at the top, so anything you place above it is out of the view. Also fixed by switching to a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Sam What about the lock? It was the detailsTextView that was the only one showing. However, it still seems as though everything is just wrapping, rather than having the layout be 100dp in height. However, switching to layout_below did bring both `TextView`s into play.

Comment: @RileyE Honestly the above method only requires one attribute, trying to finagle it by "locking" the top TextView in place will require three or more attributes... I haven't tested it since using `layout_below` is simpler. As for forcing each ListView to be 100dp tall, I know ListView likes to override the height settings in many instances. But you could try using `android:minHeight="100dp"` (and `maxHeight` if you want _exactly_ 100dp.)

Comment: Setting the minHeight worked like a charm. Thanks! Also, I'm watching the Google Talk. :) Where are the rest of your upvotes?!